# Axios headers being sent as payload

Tags: javascript, axios

I'm using axios to send a post request, here's my code:

```
const getHeaders = (token) => {
    const headers = {
        "content-type": "application/json",
    }

    if (token !== undefined) headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;

    return headers;
}

const post = async ({ url, body = {}, token }) => {
    const requestObject = {
        headers: getHeaders(token),
        ...body
    }

    console.log(requestObject);

    return await axios.post(url, requestObject);
}
```

This works when there's no token (for example, the login request), it sends it alright. However, for the next request, I pass a token to request the user details (for example), but when I look at the Chrome network tab, I see this:

[image]

So, the headers are being sent as the payload, but then, in the request headers, the "Authorization: Bearer ..." is not there. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send options you need a third argument....

```
const post = ({ url, body = {}, token }) => {
    const options = {
        headers: getHeaders(token)
    }
    return axios.post(url,body, options);
}
```

Also `async/ await` makes no sense here

Comment: Doing it like that it doesn't work, it ignores the third parameter

Comment: even the docs says... `axios.post(url[, data[, config]])` are u sure?

Comment: yeah, I tried changing it to `axios({ url, method: 'post', data: body, headers: getHeaders(token) })` and it worked so I'm leaving it like that